# Cloudformation ImportValue within ParameterOverride CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

**Problem:**
I have a cloudformation template that is supposed to retrieve code found in `CodeCommit` and push it to a `Lambda`. The code in `CodeCommit` also contains a `SAM` template with a few parameters. The `SAM` template has the following setup

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: SAM Template for Deploy Python code to Lambda

Parameters:
  ArtifactsBucket:
    Description: The artifact bucket to get the lambda code
    Type: String
  Name:
    Description: Name of the lambda function
    Type: String
  SqsARN:
    Description: AWS SQS Arn to act as a trigger for the lambda function
    Type: String
...
```

and the `CodePipeline` `Cloudformation` template has the following to override the 3 parameters present in the `SAM` template.

```
...
 - Name: Deploy
    Actions:
    - Name: Deploy
      ActionTypeId:
        Category: Deploy
        Owner: AWS
        Provider: CloudFormation
        Version: 1
      Configuration:
        ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE
        Capabilities: 'CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND,CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM'
        ChangeSetName: !Join 
          - '-'
          - - lambda
            - !Ref CodeCommitRepoName
        ParameterOverrides: !Sub |
          {
            "ArtifactsBucket": "${ArtifactsBucket}",
            "Name": "${CodeCommitRepoName}",
            "SqsARN": {"Fn::ImportValue": "My-queue:us-east-1:Queue:Arn"}
          }
...
```

The `ArtifactBucket` and the `Name` parameters are easily changed by the `!Sub` function but I am not able to have a valid value for `SqsARN` which is an imported value.

**Question**Is there anyway to include `ImportValue` in conjungtion with a `Sub` function within `ParametersOverride`?

**Attempts** I also tried to switch from

```
{"Fn::ImportValue": "My-queue:us-east-1:Queue:Arn"}
```

to

```
!ImportValue": "My-queue:us-east-1:Queue:Arn"
```

which also did not work. Remove the `!Sub` function and using a `!Ref` function yields the same output/problem as with `ImportValue`.

Comment: Can you clarify that `My-queue:us-east-1:Queue:Arn` is the actual name of your export in CFN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key thing to remember is, using JSON within YAML

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)

> You can't use the short form of !ImportValue when it contains a !Sub.
> It is valid for AWS CloudFormation, but not valid
> for YAML:

Assuming Environment as Parameter, Here is a working example of Sub >> ImportValue >> Sub

```
        Value: !Sub
            - '{
              "sqsUrl": "${sqsUrl}",
              }'
            - {
                  sqsUrl: { 'Fn::ImportValue': { 'Fn::Sub': 'QueUrl-${Environment}' } }
              }
```

Applying it to above example might look something like below(using ssm for testing)

```
Parameters:
    Environment:
        Type: String
        Default: DV
    ArtifactsBucket:
        Type: String
        Default: TestBucket
    CodeCommitRepoName:
        Type: String
        Default: Test

Resources:
    SmsLambdaParameter:
        Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter'
        Properties:
            Name: !Sub
                - '/${EnvFullUpper}/My-Param/Test'
                - { EnvFullUpper: !Ref Environment }
            Type: 'String'
            Value: !Sub
                - '{
                  "ArtifactsBucket": "${ArtifactsBucket}",
                  "Name": "${CodeCommitRepoName}",
                  "SqsARN": "${SqsArn}"
                  }'
                - { SqsARN: { 'Fn::ImportValue': { 'Fn::Sub': 'QueueArn-${Environment}' } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array form of [Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html):

```
!Sub
  - String
  - Var1Name: Var1Value
    Var2Name: Var2Value
```

which would result in:

```
        ParameterOverrides: !Sub 
            - |
              {
                "ArtifactsBucket": "${ArtifactsBucket}",
                "Name": "${CodeCommitRepoName}",
                "SqsARN": "${SqsARNImport}"
              }
            - SqsARNImport: !ImportValue <name-of-your-queue-export>
```

Comment: This is not working, i just tested it out, It is throwing an error message when I apply cloudformation, saying yaml `Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line xx, column xx)` , i don't beleive use can use !ImportValue within !Sub, [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Hi. You have to check your indentations. This is correct pattern.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala Also I'm not using !Sub in the `ImportValue` statement as OP does not use it either.